# can't figure out missing return statement error

Tags: java, netbeans, jdbc, sqlexception

I am actually trying to fit something like the following in my code which can be found in the link mentioned  below the code:

```
Statement stmt;
ResultSet rs;
boolean done = false;
int i = 0;
while(!done) {
    try {
        stmt = connections[i].createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from aTable");
        rs.beforeFirst();
        while(rs.next()) {
            // Do whatever you need with the result set
        }
        done = true;
    } catch(SQLException e) {
        // Catch the exception and try with the next connection
        i++;
    }
}
```

Link : https://ideone.com/as1XI8

So, I have added `int i` & `boolean done` variables on Line #83 & 84
 Added while loop starting from line 91 and setting done = true in line 380

Finally, I am incrementing the variable `i(i++)` on line 389 and closing the while loop on 
 line 463 with the brace.

After doing this, I am getting an error on line 80 ( starting brace just before `int iterations = 0;`) in 
 Netbeans saying that `"missing return statement".`

I already have a return statement on line #460 and can't figure out why I am getting this error.

Could anyone please download the code in your Netbeans/Eclipse and let me know what is wrong?

Thanks !!

Comment: Where is line 460? You haven't shown any return statement in the code you've posted.

Comment: make sure that your method will reach the return statement in any case

Comment: @JonSkeet - the code for this is in the link that the OP posted: https://ideone.com/as1XI8

Comment: It really doesn't help that you've got a nearly-400-line method, full of unconventional names and nasty formatting. It's also not clear what this has to do with SqlException. Oh, and you're inviting SQL injection attacks. To be honest, at this point I would just start again, and try to write the code with much smaller methods.

Comment: @CJBS: Sure, but all the relevant code should be *in the question* rather than at a link. There's too much code there to properly include in a question, so the OP should cut it down *themselves* to form a short but complete example.

Comment: You need to check all the execution paths in your code to make sure that they all reach a return statement. You have a few {{{ at the end of your method, which probably means that you're missing a return

Comment: @JonSkeet True, especially since the linked code will most likely be gone, whilst this question will remain here for others to review.

Comment: The compiler cannot be sure whether the `while (!done)` loop will end -- and you don't return out of this `while` loop. Hence the error. Otherwise, as mentioned, a refactoring is most urgent at this point.

Comment: Hi guys, Thanks for your help. It worked.My apologies for the bad formatting but that website where I posted my code converted my formatted code from net beans to a messy one and the code wasn't editable. Does anyone know a good website like sqlfiddle/JSfiddle where I can place my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `return after the while loop` is done ! You are return inside the while loop !

Just `take your return statement` after one of the braces and see the **magic**

**NOTE** Please avoid putting down the whole code (escp. this type of messy code), it becomes a pain to go through it ! Take some time to format and make it `human readable` !

*Anyone can write codes that machine can read, its important to write codes that humans can read !*

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can see the magic :) .

My apologies for bad formatting !!

Comment: For some reason , only first IP adddress is executing and loop is not executing other IP addresses, am i incrementing the variable at the right place?

Answer (score 1):

As your code format is far from practical, after the return statement in line 460, you have three closing brackets - one for the class, one for the method and one for the while loop, I assume - ensure, that there is a return statement at the end of the method every time, in your case, just move the return statement to the end of the method.

Also, please learn how to format your code, this error has clearly been avoidable by correct formatting and indentation.

Answer (score 0):

Your return statement is at wrong position. It is in the while loop.
write your return statement at line number 462

Answer (score 0):

You need return statement for case when done is true and while loop won't even start. Just add one more return with null or new ResultSet.